# Could not get unknown property 'assembleRelease' while using gradle 2.14.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When using older version then **gradle 2.14.1** then below statement compiled and
run successfully but after updating with **gradle 2.14.1**, its not working.

**code:**

```
assembleRelease.dependsOn 'increaseVersionCodeAndName'
```

Thanks,

Devang

Comment: latest android studio force to use latest version of gradle.

Comment: close ANdroid Studio, go to your project directory and find folder `.gradle` (it's one of hidden resources, so first make it visible) and delete them. AS would on next run recreate this project

Comment: Please paste ur gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

You may change your task `increaseVersionCodeAndName` that it will depend on release like:

```
task increaseVersionCodeAndName() << {
    //your code
    dependsOn 'assembleRelease'
}
```

Instead of calling gradle `assemble` call your own gradle task `increaseVersionCodeAndName`